# How to group data from JsonResponse in python?

Tags: python

I have a JSON data like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 247,
    "agency_account_id": 2,
    "expiration_date": "2021-02-21"
  },
  {
    "id": 248,
    "agency_account_id": 2,
    "expiration_date": "2021-03-22"
  },
  {
    "id": 246,
    "agency_account_id": 3,
    "expiration_date": "2021-02-21"
  },
  {
    "id": 249,
    "agency_account_id": 3,
    "expiration_date": "2021-03-13"
  }
]
```

I want to for loop through the json and then group them by agency_account_id, maybe store them in an array or list or anything. Once saved, print them out with an output like this

```
for agency_id in agency_account_id:
    print(agency_id.id)
```

Comment: What is "Do something" exactly? And does it apply only to a single ID or multiple... eg: did you want a lookup structure of ids->something or just scan your list once for certain ids etc...

Comment: I have multiple agency_id on my json response.  My do something is about what to do if agency_id is 2 or 3 , etc. They run different functions.

Comment: How big is your json response? (presumably - famous last words - not large)... can you start by just building a lookup... eg: `lookup = {}; for item in your_json_response: lookup.setdefault(item['agency_account_id'], []).append(item)`... then go from there?

Comment: I edited my question hopefully to clarify my question.

Comment: @JonClements My json response, rn is short since my data is still small. But it would scale sometime in the future(maybe).

Comment: Okay... so as said above... group by the above then loop over the dictionary's items?

Comment: Yes. How to group them?

Comment: my comment above?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

assume 'a' as your data

```
from collections import defaultdict
dct = defaultdict(list)
{dct[i['agency_account_id']].append(i['id']) for i in a}
```

Using key in result you will get a list

```
output :
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {2: [247, 248], 3: [246, 249]})
```

Comment: After this operation if you want all agency_account_id you can call dct.keys(), it will return a list and say dct[2] will return ids linked to it

Comment: Thank you for your response. rn this is as close as what I had in mind. my next question would be, how to iterate dct? I can do `for x in dct: print x` But this only prints the ids' 2 and 3. I would like to loop them and get the values 247, 248 etc.

Comment: When I say loop, maybe first iteration of x, print 247, 248. 2nd iteration of x, print 246, 249.

Comment: ```for x in dct:print(dct[x])``` try this

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
y=json.loads(
'''[
  {
    "id": 247,
    "agency_account_id": 2,
    "expiration_date": "2021-02-21"
  },
  {
    "id": 248,
    "agency_account_id": 2,
    "expiration_date": "2021-03-22"
  },
  {
    "id": 246,
    "agency_account_id": 3,
    "expiration_date": "2021-02-21"
  },
  {
    "id": 249,
    "agency_account_id": 3,
    "expiration_date": "2021-03-13"
  }
]'''

)
for x in y:
    if(x["id"]==247):
        print(x["expiration_date"])
```

This is how JSON data can be handled

Comment: I know how the for x in y loop works. But my question is about grouping them by agency_account_id.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert response to DataFrame then you could do whatever.

if it's from JSON, then use

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json.loads(json_sting), orient='columns')
```

If it's from the given list in your example, then use

```
df = pd.DataFrame(given_list)
```

you will get

```
    id  agency_account_id expiration_date
0  247                  2      2021-02-21
1  248                  2      2021-03-22
2  246                  3      2021-02-21
3  249                  3      2021-03-13
```

To group by

```
df.groupby(['agency_account_id']).count()
```

to return count as

```
                   id  expiration_date
agency_account_id                     
2                   2                2
3                   2                2
```

If you need further operations, check `groupby` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

Comment: I got the output the same. Now how do I get all id of agency_account_id dynamically? Sorry. I am still new to python itself and first time seeing this DataFrame.

Comment: preferably, append them in an array or list or something.

Comment: @rodjames I have updated the answer to include `groupby`. It depends on what you want to do after grouping them.

Comment: Nice. but what happened to the ID? the 246, 24, 248, 249? Sorry if I am pestering you about this.

Comment: Oh it is counting instead.